# Robust process keeper for Erlang app

Tags: erlang, erlang-otp

My Erlang app will create up to 1'000'000 processes. Each process will be a gen_server. From time to time each process will get some messages.

I am looking for a robust process keeper for my Erlang app. Any ideas what is a best match for my needs?

Additional info:

Read here why build-in process registry is not good enough for tasks like mine: https://github.com/uwiger/gproc/blob/master/doc/erlang07-wiger.pdf

Comment: What do you mean by process keeper? What's wrong with the usual supervisor pattern?

Comment: process keeper = process index. Supervisor pattern is designed for other type of tasks. I was looking for a process register/index/keepe - something that will hold and take care about my croud of processes.

Comment: Do you mean like a connection pool?

Comment: Not realy. Connection pool is something that holds tens or hundreds of things, but I need to handle milion of those things... It is really big difference.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do you need a better process registry? If so, take a look at [gproc](https://github.com/uwiger/gproc). It's a powerful alternative to standard OTP registered processes that, among others, suffers from the hard one million tuple limit of the Erlang VM.

Comment: Right! gproc! Could not remember the name myself even it is in my fav list on github... Thank you!